Can't target any element using Appium from AWS Amplify login page
I'm trying to setup Appium testing for my Expo React Native App. The app uses AWS Amplify for many functionalities, including the authentication:
...
export default withAuthenticator(App)
...

(https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react-native/connected-components/authenticator)
I am trying to setup test to login, but despite being able to find elements on Appium Inspector, I am not able to target them in my test.
Using Appium Inspector, I am able to locate the element as:
ios class chain: **/XCUIElementTypeOther[name == "amplify__text-field__input-container"][2] -
ios predicate string: name == "amplify__text-field__input-container" AND label == "Enter your Password Show password" 
xpath: //XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="amplify__text-field__input-container" and @Label="Enter your Password Show password"] 

Screenshot of what I see in Appium Inspector
I tried targeting the element using all three methods, but it doesn't seem to work:
const passwordInput = await driver.$('-ios predicate string:name == "amplify__text-field__input-container" AND label == "Enter your Password Show password"')
const passwordInput = await driver.$("-ios class chain:**/XCUIElementTypeOther[`name == \"amplify__text-field__input-container\"`][2]");
const passwordInput = await driver.$('//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="amplify__text-field__input-container" and @label="Enter your Password Show password"]');

with error stating that element could not be found:
Error: Can't call addValue on element with selector "//XCUIElementTypeOther\[@name="amplify__text-field__input-container" and @Label="Enter your Password Show password"\]" because element wasn't found

I've also tried recording from appium inspector and using the generated code, but no success (tap email input field, add value, tap password input field, add value, tap login)
const el1 = await driver.$("-ios class chain:**/XCUIElementTypeOther[`name == \"amplify__text-field__input-container\"`][1]");
await el1.addValue("test1");
const el2 = await driver.$("-ios class chain:**/XCUIElementTypeOther[`name == \"amplify__text-field__input-container\"`][2]");
await el2.addValue("test12345");
const el3 = await driver.$("accessibility id:amplify__button");
await el3.click();

The command I use to execute test is npm wdio run ./wdio.conf.js
Is there something special needed to test AWS Cognito page? or is there a way to bypass this for testing only?
Thanks in advance for any advice.
